# php how to replace slashes from beginning and end?

Tags: php

how to replace slashes from beginning and end?

So for example, all of these:

/this/that/

/this/that

this/that/

////////this/that////////////

... become:
this/that

Answer (score 10):

Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) with the second argument the character(s) that you want to trim.

```
$result = trim('/this/that//', '/');
//$result is now 'this/that'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`ltrim`](http://www.php.net/ltrim) and [`rtrim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$txt = '////////this/that////////////';
echo rtrim(ltrim($txt, '/'), '/');
```

**Result:**

```
this/that
```

Comment: This answer is not incorrect. Don't understand the down-votes.

Comment: @sshow I didn't downvote, but I think it is because the answer isn't quite as good as it could have been (e.g. it uses `rtrim` and `ltrim` rather than trim)

Comment: @Yacoby: Thanks for your comment but I think answer isn't **wrong**. Doesn't deserve downvote if no upvote at all :)

Comment: The title to the down-vote is "this answer is *not* useful", which this answer obviously is, since it answers the question.

Comment: This code is self-obfuscated. Being unobvious it makes reading and supporting harder.

Comment: @sshow In my opinion it "is not useful" because it doesn't do it in the "best possible" way. I didn't downvote as I am clearly biased on this issue.

Comment: Works just the same just bit more code. So technically its not wrong.